# how to make the content get the same height of the container?

Tags: html, css

So i was just experimenting and made this. Problem is that all the elements in the div exit the container's height and idk how to make it so that they stay inside.

```css
.col-4{
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;}
.row{
  width: 300px;
  height:auto;
}

.img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
 
}
```

```html
<head>
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-4 col-12-mobile">
<article class="item">
<a href="student performancve prediction.html" ckass="image fit" target="_blank">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/jV8T6cL/image.jpg" class="img" alt="" />

<h3>Student Performance Prediction:<br>
A Deep Learning Approach </h3>
<hr style="height:1pt; visibility:hidden;" />
<p style="font-size:12pt; margin-left:1.5em; color:rgb(180, 180, 180); float:left;" align="left">R, Python</p>
<p style="font-size:12pt; margin-right:1.5em; color:rgb(11809, 180, 180); float:right; line-height:1.5em;" align="right">Last Updated: <br>11 Jan, 2020</p>
<p><br></p>

</a>
</article>
</div>


</div>

</body>
</head>
```

Comment: You have a few markup problems here. The ```<a>``` class has a typo. Class is Spelled ckass. Also, it's not a good idea to wrap the ```<a>``` tag around so many elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: auto` in css like below

```
.col-4{
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto
}
```